# How can I run SpotBugs using Java for static code analysis?

Tags: java, groovy, findbugs, static-code-analysis, spotbugs

I was working on injecting of groovy scripts dynamically in Java. So before executing those scripts, I want to get sure of that they do not have potential bugs using [SpotBugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs) (static code analyzer).
Here is the Psuedo-Code:

> Here it should return the infinite loop bug.

```
String script = "class Hello { static void main(String []args) { def i = 0; while ( i <= 0) { i = i - 1; } } } ";
List<Bugs> bugs = SpotBugs.getBugs(script);
if (bugs == null) {
    execute(script);
}
```

So how to do the `SpotBugs.getBugs(script)` using java, the input script will not be hard-coded as in above example, but will be dynamically fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Easiest API

The easiest way is to write the compiled code to class files (in a temp directory if needed). By having compiled class as file, you will be able to use the [`FindBugs`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.spotbugs/spotbugs/3.1.0/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/FindBugs.html) class which provide an API to configure the scope and rules without playing with internal classes that are subject to changes.

## Groovy dynamic (default) vs static compiling

However, the main obstacle you'll face is that groovy **bytecode** is too obfuscated for SpotBugs. For the call to function `abc()`, you will not see an invoke to method `abc` in the bytecode. It will be a reference to a global functions map that is created at runtime. Groovy has a mode to compile to a less dynamic format. This mode does not allow functions to be created at runtime. You can check the configuration to instruct the compiler for the static mode in this test repo: https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs-demos/tree/master/groovy-simple. This is, however, a Gradle compilation not a programmatic API that received a String as code.

Comment: I was trying to use FindBugs2 API, as stated in SpotBugsRule (test). Was getting error in `SystemProperties.getBoolean("findbugs.listOrder"); '(line 85: FindBugs2.class)

Comment: More info and stack trace for above error: [Github Issue](https://github.com/spotbugs/discuss/issues/34#issuecomment-376065110)

Answer (score 0):

seems like SpotBugs should run using maven, which means it will package and include only the groovy scripts that are valid.
hence, you will not need to check before execution.

Comment: For my use case, groovy scripts are not included in package, I get groovy scripts dynamically from a non trusted source, and I have to run that. So before running them, I want to validate it for certain error using SpotBugs.

Comment: check their test cases..https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/blob/release-3.1/spotbugs-tests/src/test/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/DetectorsTest.java

Comment: setUpEngine("build/classes/java/main/");

        engine.execute();

        // If there are zero bugs, then something's wrong
        assertFalse("No bugs were reported. Something is wrong with the configuration", bugReporter.getBugCollection()
                .getCollection().isEmpty());

Comment: go through the setUpEngine, and modify it, to load the files you need...

Comment: I think setUpEngine is for eclipse plugin, and doesn't work otherwise. Any other way you found?

Comment: its a private method inside the link above, you will need to reimplement, and load the files you need...

Comment: `setUpEngine` uses `FindBugs2` class, I am getting an error in instantiation of that class. More info: [Github Issue](https://github.com/spotbugs/discuss/issues/34#issuecomment-376065110). If you have worked with it earlier, please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: I didn't work with it, but i suggest you will download the files from github, and try to run the tests...